# Fast and reliable desktop-grade drive

Tags: performance, hard-drive

I'm looking for desktop-grade drives to build a distributed storage cluster (chunks are replicated on software level). I don't mind their mission critical ability, which clearly impossible with their desktop designation instead of 24x7, but will appreciate a brand / model that will cause the least faults, while still being fast.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have lots of time to spend poring over really obtuse forum posts, etc I would advise looking on NewEgg for the hard disks with the most positive reviews and go from there.

There's no rule of thumb for good drives vs. not good drives -- there's only 3 companies making these things these days, and every one has shipped lemons.

Answer (score 1):

The line "there's only 3 companies making these things these days, and every one has shipped lemons." ought to be included automatically in response to any question about hard drive reliability.

Personally, I've had good reliability from the WD RE series of disks, compared to their Caviar disks which had a pretty bad record in our desktops.  We had about 2% of the Caviars die by the time they were 3 years old, whereas we haven't had any REs die in the last 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a few Hitachi HDT 72 1010 SLA360 drives here and I'm quite happy with them. They are officially designated 24/7, are rather cheap and none of the four I have crashed (yet - never trust disks).

Comment: "never trust disks" - if only more people believed me when I said that..